# Is there a way I can frame (or something else) a label with a border width of just 1pm and a radius?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm told that this code cannot be made to have a small border width:

```
<Frame Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" OutlineColor="Black">
    <Label x:Name="faveIconLabel" 
           Style="{StaticResource mediumIcon}" 
           Margin="0,2,0,0" 
           HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
           FontFamily="FontAwesome" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</Frame>
```

Is there a way that I can make a frame or something else have a border width setting and a radius setting? What I would like to do is to have this work for iOS and Android so maybe I need to use a custom renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you can achieve this with custom renderers:

**Step 1: Create new `Frame` Class:**

```
public class RoundedCornerFrame : Frame
{
}
```

**Step 2: Create Android CustomRenderer:**

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using VerySimpleSample;
using VerySimpleSample.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RoundedCornerFrame), typeof(RoundedCornerFrameRenderer))]
namespace VerySimpleSample.Droid
{
    public class RoundedCornerFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.Draw(canvas);
            DrawOutline(canvas, canvas.Width, canvas.Height, Element.CornerRadius; //set corner radius
        }
        void DrawOutline(Canvas canvas, int width, int height, float cornerRadius)
        {
            using (var paint = new Paint { AntiAlias = true })
            using (var path = new Path())
            using (Path.Direction direction = Path.Direction.Cw)
            using (Paint.Style style = Paint.Style.Stroke)
            using (var rect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height))
            {
                float rx = Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius);
                float ry = Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius);
                path.AddRoundRect(rect, rx, ry, direction);

                paint.StrokeWidth = 1f;  //set outline stroke
                paint.SetStyle(style);
                paint.Color = Element.OutlineColor.ToAndroid(); //set outline color
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Create iOS CustomRenderer:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using UIKit;
using CoreGraphics;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(RoundedCornerFrameRenderer ))]
namespace VerySimpleSample.Droid
{
    public class RoundedCornerFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        public RoundedCornerFrameRenderer ()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Element != null)
            {
                // needed because of a bug in Xamarin that doesn't set the color
                // https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44600
                // https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76737/xamarin-color-same-value-different-tone-in-ios
                Layer.BackgroundColor = ToCGColor(Element.BackgroundColor);
            }
      }

        public static CGColor ToCGColor(Color color)
        {
            return new CGColor(CGColorSpace.CreateSrgb(), new nfloat[] { (float)color.R, (float)color.G, (float)color.B, (float)color.A });
        }

    }
}
```

**Step 4: Use `RoundedCornerFrame` in xaml:**

```
<local:RoundedCornerFrame Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5, 5, 0, 0" OutlineColor="#0f8217" CornerRadius="5">
    <Label Text="Hello"/>
</local:RoundedCornerFrame>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Another useful tip is that you can use `Padding` to change the appearance according to your needs. This is with `Padding="5"` on the `CoundedCornerFrame` control:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your very well documented answer. I will check this out and let you know if I have any questions.

Comment: Hi,  I noticed that the name for Android is RoundedCornerFrameRenderer and iOS is One.iOS.OneFrameRenderer.  Can you maybe change the iOS one to match as I think it would be confusing for others.  Thanks

Comment: Dennis,  Did you make a mistake when copying the iOS version.  I don't even see how that makes any rounded corner.  Also I think to be useful a renderer would need to accept a value for the corner radius.  You have a hard coded solution which might not be good for most others needs.

Comment: @Alan2 I edited my answer. Hope iOS works now, unfortunately I can't test iOS code. You could further improve it my addind a custom property to `RoundedCornerFrame` which sets the border width.